# Castle Windsor dependency injection to properties

Tags: castle-windsor

I am trying to add something (I don't know what that something is) to Castle Windsor that will detect when I'm trying to create an instance of a class that derives from `System.Activities.Activity`, Windsor would inspect the properties of type `InArgument<T>` and resolve values for these arguments before returning the created instance to the callee.

What are the steps for doing something like this?

Basically, I would have something like this:

```
var someActivity = container.Resolve<SomeActivity>();
```

Then Windsor would detect that `SomeActivity` derives from `Activity`, it would inspect the properties of type `InArgument<T>` on `SomeActivity` and would resolve values for those properties from the container itself.

But `SomeActivity` could be any `Activity`, not necessarily specifically `SomeActivity`.

Answer (score 0):

Windsor by default sets all the properties it can resolve.

Comment: I'm guessing the issue is that the OP has registered `T` but not `InArgument<T>` and wants Windsor to resolve `T` for properties of type `InArgument<T>`. Otherwise the question is too uninteresting exactly for the reason that you give.

Comment: why are you complicating stuff by adding another layer of indirection?

Comment: Huh, I'm not complicating anything. I'm just trying to guess what the OP is really asking.

Comment: Oh, I see what you mean. `InArgument<T>` is part of Windows Workflow. It is what is used to represent data that flows into a workflow.

Comment: oh right I see. I guess you could have InArgument type in the contaiiner then, or use a `ISubDependencyResolver` to provide the values.